# How to change msexcell cell format in Node.js by using exceljs

Tags: node.js, exceljs

```
const Excel = require('exceljs');
let workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
let workSheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);
workSheet.getCell('W2').font = {color: {argb: "004e47cc"}};
```

this code sets font color for entire row, not just W2 cell. Same happens if I do:

```
let row2 = workSheet.getRow(2);
row2.getCell(23).font = {color: {argb: "004e47cc"}}; //W2
```

So how do I set cell style just for certain cell?

Comment: works fine for me...try updating the module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked for me as well, but your code doesn't work as-is.  `workbook.getWorksheet(1)` is failing, since you haven't created any worksheets in the new workbook you created.

This code generates a valid .xlsx file where cell W2 has the color you want:

```
const Excel = require('exceljs');
const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
const workSheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Sheet');
workSheet.getCell('W2').font = {color: {argb: "004e47cc"}};
workbook.xlsx.writeFile('foo.xlsx');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "getWorksheet('sheetName')" instead of "getWorksheet(sheetNo)", This works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. About styling:

This one should work properly:

`row2.getCell(23).style = {font:{color: {argb: "004e47cc"}}}`

Because, as a default all cells in a row referencing into one `style` object and the `font` is only a getter and setter to [.style.font](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/blob/master/lib/doc/cell.js#L59-L65)

2. About accessing into worksheet:

> Use "getWorksheet('sheetName')" instead of "getWorksheet(sheetNo)", This works fine for me.

So, in exceljs we provide two ways to get worksheet:

```
// FIRST:
// wb.getWorksheet(ws:string|number):Worksheet
wb.getWorksheet('sheetName')
wb.getWorksheet(sheetId) 
// NOTE: sheetId is number written into worksheet,
// it's not a index in array - just a number from Excel. 
// So for some files you read sheetId may be for instance: 10, 9, 999
// I recommend to avoid using  ws.getWorksheet(NUMBER).

// SECOND:
// wb.worksheets: Array<Worksheet>
wb.worksheets[1];
wb.worksheets[2];
wb.worksheets[wb.worksheets.lenght-1];
// I am big fan of using this way :)
```

Comment: I've just updated ExcelJs readme, I added some explanation about accessing to worksheet:
https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs#access-worksheets